# Spring boot console app global exception handling using Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler is not being invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, console-application

I have a spring boot console app (i.e. not MVC or REST) and I need to setup a global exception handling. @ControlerAdvice/@Messagehandler are obviously not and option so I'm trying to use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler instead. Observation is that after throwing an exception, the Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandlerhandler is not being invoked. I'm looking for advice as to why this is not working or recommendation on using a different stratgy

```
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
public class BatchLoaderCliApplication  {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t,e)->System.out.println("in exception handler"));

    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
                   System.out.println(1/0)
                };
        }
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:773)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at com.somecom.batchloader.BatchLoaderCliApplication.main(BatchLoaderCliApplication.java:54)
**Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero**
    at com.somecom.batchloader.BatchLoaderCliApplication.lambda$1(BatchLoaderCliApplication.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770)
    ... 5 more

Answer (score 1):

*Spring Boot* has a default mechanism using registered `SpringBootExceptionReporter` implementations. By default there is one delegating to `FailureAnalyzer` implementations and finally passing results to `FailureAnalysisReporter`.

For custom handling you can either

- register your custom [`SpringBootExceptionReporter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootExceptionReporter.html) to extend/override default behaviour
- register custom [`FailureAnalyzer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/diagnostics/FailureAnalyzer.html) to handle specific exceptions
- register a custom [`FailureAnalysisReporter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/diagnostics/FailureAnalysisReporter.html) to handle all failures different

Registration is done by adding a local file `META-INF/spring.factories` which contains a (properties format) line with the full spring interface name as key and all your implementations as value (comma separated).